# What's wrong with my code?. Learning Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I am new to bootstrap and still learning on it. I am current working with this project of my own. I manage to view a data table withouth using a parameter. In my project I have two data tables after I onclick in my first datable a parameter should pass to the second data table(empty) `(sample an ID)` and it will load the data. Without the parameter in my controller and use a specific value in `a.BookTransactionHdrID == 100` it will load. But that's not what I want to happen. Anyone have an idea?.

[image]

**JS CODE**

```
function fnGetStudentBook(getId) {

    if (getId != 0 || getId != undefined || getId != "") {
        dtStudBook = $('#dtBook').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            processing: true,
            info: true,
            retrieve: true,
            destroy: true,
            search: true,
            stateSave: true,
            lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 20, -1], [5, 10, 20, "All"]],
            ajax: {
                "url": "/LS/GetStudentBook",
                "data": function (d) {
                    d.BookTransactionDtlID = getId;
               }
            },
            columns:
    [
             { data: "BookId", title: "", visible: false, searchable: false },
              //{ data: "Barcode", title: "Barcode",  searchable: false },
            { data: "Author", title: "Author" }
  //   { data: "Title", title: "Title", sClass: "alignRight" },
  //   { data: "DatePublish", title: "Date Publish", sClass: "alignRight" },
  //   { data: "PlacePublish", title: "Place Publish" },
  //   { data: "NameOfPublisher", title: "Name Of Publisher"},
  //   { data: "ISBN", title: "ISBN"},
  //   { data: "BookTransactionDtlID", title: "", visible: false }
      ]
        });
    }
    else {
        //do nothing..
    }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public JsonResult GetStudentBook(int getId)
    {
       // int getId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["getId"]);
        var Data = new List<object>();
        Data = (from a in db.BookTransactionDtls
                join b in db.Books on a.BookID equals b.BookID
                where a.BookTransactionTypeID == 3 && a.BookTransactionHdrID == getId
                select new
                {
                    BookId = a.BookID,
                    //Barcode = b.Barcode,
                    Author = b.Author
                    //Title = b.Title,
                    //DatePublish = b.DatePublished,
                    //PlacePublish = b.PlacePublished,
                    //NameOfPublisher = b.NameOfPublisher,
                    //ISBN = b.ISBN,
                    //BookTransactionDtlID = a.BookTransactionDtlID
                }).OrderBy(a => a.BookId).ToList<object>();
        return gf.DataTableAjaxHandlerClientSide(Data);
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <i class="fa fa-list fa-fw"></i>Book
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive nowrap"
                        role="grid" style="width: 10%;" id="dtBook">
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Code for onclick for passing the parameter**

```
var getId = 0;
var dtStudBook = "";
var dtBorrowerName = $('#dtBorrowerName').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    processing: true,
    info: true,
    search: true,
    stateSave: true,
    order: [[1, "desc"]],
    lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 20, -1], [5, 10, 20, "All"]],
    ajax: { "url": "/LS/GetBorrower" },
    columns:
        [
            { data: "BorrowerID", title: "", visible: false, searchable: false },
            { data: "IDNo", title: "ID Number" },
            { data: "Name", title: "Complete Name", sClass: "alignRight", width: " 100px" },
            { data: "BookTransactionHdrID", title: "BookTransactionHdrID", visible: false, searchable: false }
        ]
});



$('#dtBorrowerName tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    getId = dtBorrowerName.row(this).data().BookTransactionHdrID;
    alert(getId);
    fnGetStudentBook(getId)
 });
```

Comment: My best guess is that you're passing in an invalid `getId`, but that's a guess since you haven't included in your question how you are calling this function.  Note that your condition `getId != 0 || getId != undefined || getId != ""` is always true: I suspect you want `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: @LukeWoodward sorry I didn't bring my whole codes. I am calling this function on onclick in my first data table.

Comment: @LukeWoodward from first data table onclick body i can get the value `for example 110` and I pass in this function.

Comment: Neither of your two comments clarify your question any further.  Edit the question to include all of the code.

Comment: That doesn't look like the right code.  The code you've added calls `fnGetPersonOrder` but the function you've defined at the top is named `fnGetStudentBook`.

Comment: @LukeWoodward sorry for the miss called functions. I copied the old name of function

Comment: The alert box in your screenshot contains a URL.  Have you visited that URL?  More to the point, is there anything that comes up in your browser's developer tools?

Comment: @LukeWoodward I don't see anything in my Dev Tools aside from that prompt alert. I visited it.

Comment: Actually, I see that you don't pass `getId` to your controller. Try to use this url: `"url": "/LS/GetStudentBook?getId=" + getId`.

Comment: The controller looks like Java... `public`? C++, C  `int`?

Comment: @zer00ne its not java :). I am using asp.net mvc4

Comment: @dashtinejad I will try it after office hour because its my personal learning. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can something like this in your `ajax` like the way of jqgrid.

```
 ajax: {
        "url": "/LS/GetStudentBook?getId=" + getId
       },
```

and also if you are familiar with `["Session"]`. In your code the `Request.QueryString["getId"]` is similar to Session.

Hope it helps. Cheers.

Comment: Yes i am familiar with session that's what we are using here. and also thanks for the answer I thought that way of ajax coding is only for jqgrid.. Thanks.

Comment: Sure glad to help you.