# Can't refresh grid after deleting row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using inline editing and I have a custom delete button on the inline nav panel that deletes the row from the database. I have a grid refresh var (that I got from one of Oleg's responses on here) that works fine for add's and edit's but I can't get it to work on my delete button. Here's the code for the add/edit functions which refreshes fine:

```
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid("navGrid", '#pager', {add:false, edit:false, del:false, search:false, refresh:false});   
jQuery("#list").jqGrid("inlineNav",'#pager',{add:true, addicon:"ui-icon-plus", del:false, reloadAfterSubmit:true, edit:true, editicon:"ui-icon-pencil", search:false, addParams: {position: "last", addRowParams: editOptions}, editParams: editOptions});
```

Here's the code for my delete button which doesn't work:

```
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid("navButtonAdd",'#pager',{buttonicon:'ui-icon-trash', onClickButton:function(){$.get('delgridrow.php?id='+detailid);}, reloadAfterSubmit:false, afterSubmit: editOptions, caption:'', position:'last'});
```

And here's the var that I got from Oleg that works for the adds/edits:

```
var editOptions = {
keys: true,
successfunc: function () {
    var $self = $(list);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $self.trigger("reloadGrid");
    }, 50);
        }
 };
```

I've tried changing reloadAfterSubmit to true but that doesn't help. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#grid').trigger( 'reloadGrid' );
```

on successful deletion. It will refresh the jqgrid

Comment: @Pandeyz this method don't need parameter?. like `$("#ScanLogList").setGridParam({ datatype: 'json', url: '../URL/CS?&month=' + month }).trigger("reloadGrid");`

Comment: These params are not mandatory. When you just want to refresh the jqgrid $('#grid').trigger( 'reloadGrid' ); is enough

Comment: @Pandeyz thanks. I will try to apply it on my code. First time to see this one. If you have some time maybe also you can help me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328953/whats-wrong-with-my-code-learning-bootstrap)